# Put key values in a list of Python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dictionary that looks something like this:

```
{
    "hits": [
    {
       "_source": {
           "network": "att",
           "month": january,
           "volume": "30",
           "mass": 3,
       }
    },
    {
       "_source": {
           "network": "vzn",
           "month": june,
           "volume": "10",
           "mass": 2,
         }
     }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to take this dictionary and put some things in lists. For example, I'd like to get all the element's mass and volume and put them in a list format like so:

```
mass = [3,2]
volume = [30, 10]
```

I know I can create a loop and loop through each element of the json and add it to each list, but I was wondering if there was a built in or more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: besides using a loop, "built in or more elegant way" may just be a list-comprehension.

Comment: Depends how many keys you want to grab. You might consider a list comprehension "more elegant" but if you're grabbing 10 keys to make 10 lists, it's probably faster to do a single pass of the data in a regular `for` loop rather than 10 list comprehensions

Comment: No, there is no pre-built way to parse your bespoke data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list-comprehension option:

```
mass_list = 'mass:', [i['_source']['mass'] for i in d['hits']]

volume_list = 'volume:', [i['_source']['volume'] for i in d['hits']]
```

output:

```
print(mass_list)   # mass: [3, 2]
print(volume_list) # volume: ['30', '10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
a={
    "hits": [
    {
       "_source": {
           "network": "att",
           "month": 'january',
           "volume": "30",
           "mass": 3,
       }
    },
    {
       "_source": {
           "network": "vzn",
           "month": 'june',
           "volume": "10",
           "mass": 2,
         }
     }
  ]
}

a=a.items();

mass=[]
volume=[]

for value in a:
    for k in value[1]:
        k=list(k.items());
        volume.append(k[0][1]['volume'])
        mass.append(k[0][1]['mass'])

print(mass)
print(volume)
```